# Uber API GET/estimates/price response surge_multiplier disappeared

Tags: uber-api

today, I found GET/estimates/price end point have a change, surge_multiplier disappeared, is to say, price has been fixed, no more surge?

Answer (score 1):

Surging is based on the particular location and product setup - so if you try following request for example:

*https://sandbox-api.uber.com//v1.2/estimates/price?start_latitude=-33.865535736083984&start_longitude=151.1958770751953&end_latitude=-33.88345718383789&end_longitude=151.0906982421875*

```
"prices": [
{
  "localized_display_name": "uberX",
  "distance": 7.76,
  "display_name": "uberX",
  "product_id": "2d1d002b-d4d0-4411-98e1-673b244878b2",
  "high_estimate": 35,
  "surge_multiplier": 1,
  "minimum": 9,
  "low_estimate": 26,
  "duration": 1260,
  "estimate": "A$26-35",
  "currency_code": "AUD"
},
```

If you try it for different location:

*start_latitude=37.7752315&start_longitude=-122.418075&end_latitude=37.7752415&end_longitude=-122.518075*

You will get response without 'surge_multiplier' parameter:

```
{
  "localized_display_name": "uberXL",
  "distance": 6.62,
  "display_name": "uberXL",
  "product_id": "821415d8-3bd5-4e27-9604-194e4359a449",
  "high_estimate": 28,
  "low_estimate": 22,
  "duration": 1380,
  "estimate": "$22-28",
  "currency_code": "USD"
},
```

For more info on surging please read our [documetation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get)

EDIT done on 02/15/2018:

If you are using v1.2 request - response we are getting is based on the product setup. If the product used in the estimate request is configured to have "upfront_fare_enabled": true then we will get one fare_id - instead of estimate. So this is expected as in v1.2 with upfront_fare_enabled: true there will never be surge information (as you get a real fare + fare_id).

Please check following sentence from our documentation on "POST /v1.2/requests/estimate" endpoint:

> You should use this endpoint to get an upfront fare before requesting
>   a ride. In some products upfront fares are not enabled so you can use
>   this endpoint to determine if surge pricing is in effect for the
>   product/location. Do this before attempting to make a ride request so
>   that you can preemptively have a user confirm surge by sending them to
>   the surge_confirmation_href provided in the response. This endpoint
>   will either return an upfront fare (in the fare key) or a range
>   estimate (in the estimate key) depending on the configuration of the
>   product.

So the response you are getting back depends on product configuration specifically: "upfront_fare_enabled" field. If there is upfront fare setup (upfront_fare_enabled = true) then there will not be "surge_confirmation_href" available in the response - and response type will be one "fare": {} response - example of this is below:

```
{
  "fare": {
    "value": 5.73,
    "fare_id": "d30e732b8bba22c9cdc10513ee86380087cb4a6f89e37ad21ba2a39f3a1ba960",
    "expires_at": 1476953293,
    "display": "$5.73",
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "breakdown": [
     {
       "type": "promotion",
       "value": -2.00,
       "name": "Promotion"
     },
     {
       "type": "base_fare",
       "notice": "Fares are slightly higher due to increased demand",
       "value": 7.73,
       "name": "Base Fare"
     }
   ]
  },
  "trip": {
    "distance_unit": "mile",
    "duration_estimate": 540,
    "distance_estimate": 2.39
  },
  "pickup_estimate": 2
}
```

As you can see there is no "surge_confirmation_href" available.

If your product has "upfront_fare_enabled": false you will get estimate response with surge_confirmation_id and surge_confirmation_href as shown below:

```
{
  "estimate": {
    "surge_confirmation_href": "https:\/\/api.uber.com\/v1\/surge-confirmations\/7d604f5e",
    "high_estimate": 11,
    "surge_confirmation_id": "7d604f5e",
    "minimum": 5,
    "low_estimate": 8,
    "fare_breakdown": [
      {
        "low_amount": 1.25,
        "high_amount": 1.25,
        "display_amount": "1.25",
        "display_name": "Base Fare"
      },
      {
        "low_amount": 1.92,
        "high_amount": 2.57,
        "display_amount": "1.92-2.57",
        "display_name": "Distance"
      },
      {
        "low_amount": 2.50,
        "high_amount": 3.50,
        "display_amount": "2.50-3.50",
        "display_name": "Surge x1.5"
      },
      {
        "low_amount": 1.25,
        "high_amount": 1.25,
        "display_amount": "1.25",
        "display_name": "Booking Fee"
      },
      {
        "low_amount": 1.36,
        "high_amount": 1.81,
        "display_amount": "1.36-1.81",
        "display_name": "Time"
      }
    ],
    "surge_multiplier": 1.5,
    "display": "$8-11",
    "currency_code": "USD"
  },
  "trip": {
    "distance_unit": "mile",
    "duration_estimate": 480,
    "distance_estimate": 1.95
  },
  "pickup_estimate": 2
}
```

And finally, if you update the product to have "surge_multiplier" > 1 and product have "upfront_fare_enabled = true" you will get "fare" response - but you will not know that surging is in place - until you do ride request. In this case, you will get the response with: "status": 409 and "title": "Surge pricing is currently in effect for this product." and  "surge_confirmation" info that contains "href": "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/surge-confirmations/ride_request_id". So in order to complete your ride request - you need to redirect your user to that URL - and user needs to confirm surging. After that, you will be able to create new ride request.

resposne->

```
{
  "meta": {
    "surge_confirmation": {
      "href": "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/surge-confirmations/48165d0e-f2f4-457d-98d0-058a31b15cd7",
      "expires_at": 1510684778,
      "multiplier": 1.2,
      "surge_confirmation_id": "48165d0e-f2f4-457d-98d0-058a31b15cd7"
    }
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 409,
      "code": "surge",
      "title": "Surge pricing is currently in effect for this product."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I noticed that `v1.2` doesn't return `surge_multipliter` for UberX eventhough surge is active. Whereas if I used `v1.0` it returns the correct result.

Comment: I can confirm that surge multiplier should not be returned in v1.2. Thanks for the feedback. At some point in the future (with plenty of warning) v1 of price estimates will be deprecated.

Comment: Is there any alternative to check the surge pricing for UberX? I have a script which schedules a price check if the surge is active until there is no more surge/price drop significantly, then it will notify my phone. Since checking the price again and again from the phone is quite troublesome. Right now Im using the v1 price estimates endpoint.

Comment: @Max you can use other end point for estimate POST /requests/estimate, but needs full access

Comment: @SasaJovanovic so v1.2 onwards we don't need to confirm the user with surge pricing?

Comment: @SasaJovanovic What about these calls in "Uber Rides iOS SDK" Also please confirm the flow if surge multiplier is greater than 2. we only using Uber Rides iOS SDK

Comment: @Ramz - the process is the same for the SDK - if you get a response: "status": 409, - you will need to redirect your user to accept surge price - and after that, you need to make a new ride request by passing in "surge_confirmation_id".