# Uber API v1.2/get/estimates/price - does it support surge_multiplier or not?

Tags: uber-api

[Uber API v1.2 Documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get) `GET /estimates/price` contains an ambiguity in the definition of `surge_multiplier` support:
it is declared as one of the parameters of the response
**but** 
not presented in the example of response

Additionally **I checked** answer and comments on the similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402129/uber-api-get-estimates-price-response-surge-multiplier-disappeared) and found mutually exclusive info given there:
"surge multiplier should not be returned in v1.2." vs the answer with an example of the response containing `surge_multiplier`

so what is valid and expected behaviour for this endpoint?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue: we are getting the surge_multiplier always 1 (timeestimate request). Same time uber app and google map shows surge for same product in same location. We have tried the requests in live (sandbox false) .(iOS, objective c).

Comment: @Irina, can you check the updated answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402129/uber-api-get-estimates-price-response-surge-multiplier-disappeared - I don't want to repeat it again here.

Comment: @SasaJovanovic I've read your updated answer and I'm afraid it is not releavant to the problem we're trying to resolve here :( . Topic Started asked you about `GET /estimates/price` request and specifically about `surge_multiplier` as it is ambigously declared in the docs: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/estimates-price-get . Whereas you've updated you answer to have more details on `POST /v1.2/requests/estimate`. Can you elaborate on if/under what circumstances `GET /estimates/price` request is expected to respond with `surge_multiplier` present in the response?

Answer (score 2):

Related to the "GET /estimates/price" endpoint following is stated in Uber documentation:

> When surge is active for a particular product, its surge_multiplier will be greater than 1, but the price estimate already factors in this multiplier.

Documentation also state that there is a option to get "surge_multiplier":

> surge_multiplier  float   Expected surge multiplier. Surge is active if surge_multiplier is greater than 1. Price estimate already factors in the surge multiplier.

So if there is no "surge_multiplier" returned - it is always assumed to be equal to 1. If "surge_multiplier" is greater then 1 than this parameter should be displayed. But besides if this parameter is displayed or not - if there is a surge in place for the product - price estimate already factors in this multiplier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. All the examples from the v1.2 docs miss the `surge_multiplier` field - so the docs look confusing and provoke questions like this one. Why don't you have an example with `surge_multiplier` field included in the docs?